# Why is my graphQL query returning results without `where` filters?

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, strapi

I am working on a webapp with a nuxt/vuetify/apollo frontend. The backend is a [strapi](https://strapi.io) (v3.0.0-beta.18) server with a [graphQL endpoint](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/graphql.html) and a mongoDB database (v4.2.2)

It could be a newbie question since it's my first graphql project. I have a query for a collection called tags. It looks as follows:

```
query Tags($search: String, $selected: [ID], $limit: Int) {
  tags: tags(
    limit: $limit
    sort: "score:desc"
    where: { name_contains: $search }
  ) {
    id
    name
    description
    type
  }
  selected: tags(where: { id_in: $selected }) {
    id
    name
    description
    type
  }
}
```

That query is returning every result that should be filtered by the `where` object, while the `sort` and `limit` filters work. The behavior is the same in my frontend app and on the graphQL playground. Am I missing something?

Note that strapi [Shadow CRUD](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/graphql.html#shadow-crud) feature is enabled.

Comment: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+where

Comment: Have you verified that the value for `$selected` is defined when the query runs?

Comment: @DanielRearden Yes I did, both in my app and on the graphQL playground. Same thing for the `$search` string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I missed one of the breaking changes when upgrading strapi to the latest version. The mongose connector changed its name: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/migration-guide/migration-guide-beta.17-to-beta.18.html